How to change default Field separator value to ^ on product import?
How to change default Field separator value to ^ ?
^ is typed by default when I visit the page, so I don't have to change it manually whenever I import.
System - Data Transfer - Import - Entity Type - Products - the default Field separator value is ,


It can simply be changed from the Magento admin panel.
Just make the change in the place which you have highlighted in your screenshot.

System > Data Transfer > Import > Entity Type = Products

Update: Based on the comment from @Yohan, the actual ask is to change the value of Field Separator by default.
Answer: This field renders from the Core Magento file vendor/magento/module-import-export/Block/Adminhtml/Import/Edit/Form.php
and since the function to render this field is protected, we can't have plugin for it, so we can override the file in a custom module and change:
$fieldset->addField(
    $behaviorCode . '_' . Import::FIELD_FIELD_SEPARATOR,
    'text',
    [
        'name' => Import::FIELD_FIELD_SEPARATOR,
        'label' => __('Field separator'),
        'title' => __('Field separator'),
        'required' => true,
        'disabled' => true,
        'class' => $behaviorCode,
        'value' => ',',
    ]
);

to
$fieldset->addField(
    $behaviorCode . '_' . Import::FIELD_FIELD_SEPARATOR,
    'text',
    [
        'name' => Import::FIELD_FIELD_SEPARATOR,
        'label' => __('Field separator'),
        'title' => __('Field separator'),
        'required' => true,
        'disabled' => true,
        'class' => $behaviorCode,
        'value' => '^',
    ]
);

If you want to know how to override a block class, this link might help.
Let me know if you are having issues.

I mean how can I make ^ is typed by default when I visit the page? so I don't have to change it manually whenever I import

@Yohan, I have updated my answer. Please review and upvote if it helped.

Upvote and accept answer is done. Thank you for your help! :)
